# Bypass certificate pinning for development builds with network-security-config.xml?

Tags: android, http, ssl-certificate, retrofit2, pinning

We want to bypass SSL for certain flavours of app which is used internally.
What is the best way to do it?

Can we configure the network-security-config.xml so it ignores pinning for a particular build flavour?

Or we have to override the TrustManager class?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using gradle source sets for this kind of purpose.

`debug` source set has a network security config that does not have pinning enabled.

`release` source set has a different network security config file that has everything needed for a production configuration.

In a gradle module, these source sets sit on the top `src` level, with `main` being the default.

Comment: can you share how to disable pinning in the xml please?

Comment: Have a config such as `domain-config` and the usual stuff there without `pin-set` at all.